# docusaurus: async await in examples with live editor

Tags: docusaurus

This code inside any .mdx file

````
```jsx live
function Clock(props) {
  async function test() {
    alert(1);
  }
  test();

  return <div>Doesn't matter</div>;
}
\```
````

throws a runtime error in the live editor

```
CompileError: Transforming async functions is not implemented. Use `transforms: { asyncAwait: false }` to skip transformation and disable this error. (2:2)
1 : return (function Clock(props) {
2 :   async function test() {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I guess `babel.config.js` in a docusaurus project root doesn't affect that runtime compilation.

How can I allow `async/await` in live examples?

At the same time, that code works on [react-live demo page](https://react-live.netlify.app/).

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue about that and I confirm it does not work :)

https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/3053

Comment: yep, the issue is mine :)